# Sinatra not sending response once I add an extra method call

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
post '/payment/transactions/amount' do # => creates a new charge
content_type :json, :charset => 'utf-8'

class Transaction
def initialize(endUserId, code, referenceCode, callback=false)
  @endUserId = endUserId
  @code = code
  @referenceCode = referenceCode 
  $callback = callback
  $transId = rand(1000)                               
end 

def transId
  return $transId 
end

def callback
  return $callback
end 

def postCallback
  sleep(5)
  RestClient.post"#{$callback}", :message => 'CALLBACK SUCCESS', :content_type => :json
end  

def to_json(*a)     
  {"amountTransaction" => {
    "endUserId" => @endUserId,
    "paymentAmount" =>{
      "chargingInformation" => {"code" => @code, "description" => @description},
         "totalAmountCharged"=> "0" 
     },
     "referenceCode" => @referenceCode,
     "serverReferenceCode" =>"#{(0...6).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join}", # just an example, can be any string
     "resourceURL" => "http://localhost:4567/payment/#{@endUserId}/transactions/amount/#{Trans.transId}",
     "transactionOperationStatus" => "Processing"
 }}.to_json(*a)
end
end 

 Trans = Transaction.new(params[:endUserId],params[:code], params[:referenceCode],    params[:callback])
 jsonTrans = Trans.to_json
 receipts.addReceipt(Trans.transId,jsonTrans)
 jsonTrans 
 # fire callback
 if Trans.callback then 
  sleep(10)
  Trans.postCallback 
 end  
end
```

Problem for me is the code following #fire callback. If I omit this if...then , the jsonTrans JSON object is returned as expected. When I include the if...then to fire the callback, then the desired Trans.postcallback occurs after 5 seconds - but the preceding jsonTrans is not returned, it is simply ignored. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? To confirm, the desired behaviour is to return the jsonTrans in the HTTP response and then call the postCallback method after 5 seconds (assuming the if evaluates to true). Cheers!

**EDIT**: *Solved* by spawning a new thread:
    Thread.new{
      if Trans.callback then 
       sleep(5)
      Trans.postCallback 
     end}
    jsonTrans

Answer (score 1):

The last statement is what the method returns(outputs) so it ignores your jsonTrans in the output.

The first idea I have would be to reorder it:

```
 #... 
 Trans = Transaction.new(params[:endUserId],params[:code], params[:referenceCode],    params[:callback])
 jsonTrans = Trans.to_json
 receipts.addReceipt(Trans.transId,jsonTrans) 
 # fire callback
 if Trans.callback then 
  sleep(10)
  Trans.postCallback 
 end  
 jsonTrans
end
```

This should work if you don't expect any output from that `RestClient.post`-call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion daddz - actually I managed to solve it by wrapping by spawning a new thread:                                `Thread.new{
    if Trans.callback then 
     sleep(5)
     Trans.postCallback 
     end}
    jsonTrans`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion daddz - actually I managed to solve it by wrapping by spawning a new thread:                                `Thread.new{
    if Trans.callback then 
     sleep(5)
     Trans.postCallback 
     end}
    jsonTrans`